# How to use SwipeRefresh's refresh icon Without Listview?

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

My app consists of different activities where I use a `SwipeRefreshLayout` to refresh data in `listViews` by **swiping**. When this happen a refresh icon is displayed at the top of the screen.

However, for 2 other specific activities that contain no list view, I only want to display the refresh icon while the data is refreshing by using `pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(true);` & `pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false);`. I don't need to use it for swiping.

This is how it looks in my list view layout xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/pullToRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListView"
        android:dividerHeight="8dp"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/feedLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: so, whats the question? when to call setRefreshing(true) and setRefreshing(false)?

Comment: No, the question is can i use those methods without a list view. If yes, How? @MatiasElorriaga

Comment: @espa_network Matias said nothing about a ListView.

Comment: @cricket_007 no but he did ask what the question was ;)

Answer (score -1):

Use `SwipeRefreshLayout` as a regular layout, and call `pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(true)` when you want to show the loading wheel, and `pullToRefresh.setRefreshing(false)` to hide it.